# ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: csv, encoding, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I created two applications:

- Convert a csv(encoded in latin-1) to xml

  ```
  import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
  xml.ElementTree(xmlData).write(xmlFile, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
  ```
- Load the previous xml to my database(mysql)

  - Without parser

    ```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
    etree.parse(xmlFile)
    ```
  - Parser

    ```
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
    myparser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    etree.parse(xmlFile, parser=myparser)
    ```

Loading the CSV file an converting it to a XML file works.

**Problem**: I cannot load/parse the XML file into the Elementree

**Error Message:**

```
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/xml/etree/ElementTree.py",    line 1726, in parse
parser.feed(data)
    xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 14443, column 0
```

**Note:**

- Every file is encoded in latin-1/ISO-8859-1
- Size of the CSV file is ~1GB
- I use python v3.3
- Replacing ISO-8859-1 by latin-1 does not help

**Update:**
The row 14443 starts with(in hex): 0xc 0x44 0x4c 0x56 0x36 0x32 ...

Since parse error occurs in line 14443 with column zero the error is produced by 0xc

Comment: it would help to know what's in line 14443 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
tr -dc '[\011\012\015\040-\176\200-\377]' < input.xml > output.xml
```

This is not a optimal solution since we create another (large) file.